# auto_prepend_file breaks xdebug

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am debugging PHP 5.2(i know it's old) with PHPStorm 2016.2, 
[image]

however when i add **auto_prepend_file** or **auto_append_file** in my apache vhost file:

[image]

```
    php_value auto_prepend_file /home/abc/def/apache_prepend.php
    php_value auto_append_file /home/abc/def/apache_append.php
```

xdebug breaks.

The IDE stops at the first breakpoint then the debugging stops when i try to step over/in/out and the browser returns "no data received".

My **xdebug.conf** file:

```
#[xdebug]
php_value xdebug.remote_enable on
#php_value xdebug.default_enable on
php_value xdebug.remote_autostart off
php_value xdebug.remote_port 9000
php_value xdebug.remote_host 192.168.100.66
php_value xdebug.profiler_enable 0
php_value xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger 1
php_value xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out-%H-%R-%t
php_value xdebug.profiler_output_dir /home/abc/xdebug-profile
php_value xdebug.trace_enable_trigger 1   
#php_value xdebug.auto_trace off
php_value xdebug.trace_output_name trace.out-%H-%R-%t
php_value xdebug.trace_format 1
php_value xdebug.idekey PHPSTORM
```

Comment: Does it change anything, if you set `xdebug.auto_trace` to true?

Comment: i tried it, nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to move the **xdebug.conf** at the end of the apache virtual host like this

```
        SetEnv ENVIRONMENT dev
        php_value auto_prepend_file /home/abc/prepends/apache_prepend.php
        php_value auto_append_file /home/abc/apache_append.php

        #INCLUDE XDEBUG AT THE END 
        Include /home/abc/projects/hello/site/vhosts/xdebug_notrace.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

p.s. Later i figured out that **php_value xdebug.auto_trace off**
also fixed this bug without changing apache vhost.

Comment: Nice way to get an answer and avoid handing out a bounty :D good job.

Comment: anyway, you won't get the bounty. Read [How Bounty works to know more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: i don't care about the bounty